# After ruby update, crontab not working "bundler: not executable: bin/rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rbenv, whenever

After ruby version was updated from 2.3.1 to 2.3.7, crontab is not executable in production environment (It's working in local environment). Before update, it was working.

I'm using rbenv, so the information which I could find in Internet to solve this kind of problem like ($rvm cron setup) is not suitable for my case.

schedule.rb code is:

```
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
env :GEM_PATH, ENV['GEM_PATH']
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || :development
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/environment")
set :environment, rails_env
set :output, "#{Rails.root}/log/cron.log"

 every 1.day do
  runner "Reminder.reminder_mail"
end
```

What strange is, ruby version shows

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [x86_64-linux]
```

But the environment shows different ruby version..

```
$ bundle env
Ruby          2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 0) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

I don't know if this is a problem and how to solve.

Current setting for crontab is:

```
$ crontab -l
PATH=/home/franky/list/voendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/franky/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/rbenv/shims:~/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
GEM_PATH=””

0 0 * * * /bin/bash -l -c ‘cd /home/franky/list && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production ‘'‘Reminder.reminder_mail’'’ » /home/franky/list/log/cron.log 2>&1’
```

Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Try deleting the the Gemfile lock file and bundle install again

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried it, then

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried it, then an error ``` /gems/devise-security-0.14.0/lib/devise-security.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant DEVISE_ORM (NameError) ``` is showing. ??? Is this gem "devise-security" not compatible to ruby 2.3.7? An error message showed during bundle install in the past "ruby version must be 2.3.7 or high to use devise-security", so I updated ruby to 2.3.7... confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem with "rake db:drop" and "rake db:create"!!! 
The crontab is working again!